# How to make OnFailure method of Ajax.BeginForm, run, after determining an error occurred inside ActionMethod?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an `ajax.beginform()` like this :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create_Product", "Admin", new AjaxOptions() { OnFailure = "alert(\"Error !!!\")", HttpMethod = "post"}))
{
//blah blah
}
```

It sends the form data to an `ActionMethod` called Create_Product...
Inside this `ActionMethod`, before I save the data as a new 'product' to the database, - inside a try/catch - I check to see whether the inserted product already exists or not. And if already exists, I need to return to the view **AND** trigger/run the `OnFailure` method of the ajax form :)

Is it possible ? how is it done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the Ajax Beginform and use the normal form

```
@using(Html.Beginform("Create_Product","Admin"))
{
  <input type="text" name="productName" />
  <input type="submit" id="saveNewProduct" />
}
```

And some javascript now to handle our Ajax Saving

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){

       $("#saveNewProduct").click(function(e){
          var item=$(this);
          e.preventDefault();

          $.post("@url.Action("Create_Product","Admin")",
                                item.closest("form").serialize(),function(data){
                if(data.Status=="Exist")
                { 
                   alert("The Product already exist");
                }
                else if(data.Status=="Success")
                {
                  alert("Saved Successfully");   
                }

           });  

       });    
  });

</script>
```

Assuming your Action method Returns a `JSON` back in the below format, if it is successfully inserted

```
{   "Status": "Success"   }
```

If the Product already exist, It returns this

```
{  "Status": "Exist"  }
```

So your Action method can look like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create_Product(YourViewModel model)
{
  try
  {
     //check product exist, if yes return the below commented JSON 
     // return Json(new { Status="Exist" });
    //else , Insert the data and Return Succes in JSON
     // return Json(new { Status="Success" });
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
     // log error
    return Json(new { Status="Error" });
  }
}
```

Comment: @Ali: This gives you the flexibility to do whatever you want and do some of the things which the Helper method does not do. Personally i do not use the AjaxBegin form method and use handwriteen jQuery like above

Comment: Yeah you're right. And I just figured out the OnFailure is just a _request_ callback function. It means it just checks to see if the ajax request has NOT been "requested" somehow.
So I guess I have no other choice  ;)
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can raise an exception inside the action method, or you can set the HTTP Response's StatusCode. The OnFailure property must be set with a javascript function name that will handle or display the error message.